# Java cannot find the methods of a class

Tags: class, methods

java is giving me the error that
          Java\Workspace\PROJECTS\Farm\animalLab.java  [line: 15]
    Error: cannot find symbol
     symbol:   `method addAnimal(java.lang.String,int,Farm[])`
     location: variable farm of type Farm[]

my code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class animalLab{
   public Farm[] farm = new Farm[1000];

public void main(String[]args){
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;

while(reader.hasNext()){
  if(reader.nextLine() == "Quit")
    break;
  if(reader.nextLine()=="Add"){
    System.out.println("Enter animal to add: ");
    String add = reader.nextLine();
    farm.addAnimal(add, i, farm);
  }
```

my farm class looks something like this

```
 class Farm{
public String animal = null;

public Farm(String s){
animal = s;
```

}

```
   public String getAnimal(){
return animal;
```

}

```
public void addAnimal(String add, int i, Farm farm[]){
for (int x =0; x<farm.length; x++)
  if(farm[x] != null)
  if(farm[x].animal.equals(add)){
  System.out.println(add + " is already in the farm");
  break;
}

farm[i] = new Farm(add);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`farm` is an *array* of (many) Farm objects.

Arrays do not have an `addAnimal` method. Take time to read the error message closely.

Look at it like this...

> error: cannot find [the] **method addAnimal**
>
> location: variable farm [which is] **of type Farm[]**

Consider that `farm[x].animal` "works" (the expression `farm[x]` is of type `Farm`) -- how can this be used to fix the compilation error?

I would recommend naming variables for arrays/collection in a plural form -- e.g. `farms` -- to mitigate this sort of confusion. Also, unless there is a requirement to use an array (such as a homework assignment), I would recommend using [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) -- it makes adding and iterating items easier.

Happy coding.